# Blade looking for cache files that no longer exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a project that uses blade templating. Due to server limitations, I am required to rather than have blade generate cache files on the fly - I need to provide blade with all the cache files for the application.

Oddly, blade keeps ignoring all the cache files we're providing and seems to reference cache files that don't exist. Any idea why this is? how to prevent?

```
Warning: include(/nas/content/live/dev/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/views/cache/e44b26a14bd95cd0cdf764d863a0b4bd1848c8ba.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nas/content/live/devsnappyk/wp-content/plugins/plugin/vendor/illuminate/view/Engines/PhpEngine.php on line 43
```

Essentially, I am 100% happy to generate and ftp all the cache files over. Although, the files blade attempts reference during render time don't exist and the files we **are providing** aren't picked up by blade.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Clear Blade cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: I'm not allowed access to the server command line. Is it possible to run this command locally while running blade as a standalone component? https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade

Comment: Well, you could try to just remove everything from storage/framework/views. That is basically what view:clear does.